# Referring to an entity from another page

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Google App Engine for creating a page with a form to create an entity called "tutorial". Then when hit next, the user has another form in order to create a chapter for the tutorial previously created. My problem is bringing the reference of the "tutorial" to the "chapter"

handler for the new tutorial page:

```
class NewTut(FuHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('newTut.html')
    def post(self):
        title = self.request.get("title")
        tags = self.request.get("tags")
        tut = Tutorial(title=title, tags=tags)
        tut.put()

        self.redirect('/newchap' #should i put here 'tut'?#)
```

This part works perfectly but then how do I use this `tut` when creating a chapter?

handler for the new chapter page:

```
class NewChap(FuHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('newChapter.html')

    def post(self):
        tutorial = Tutorial(??????)
        title = self.request.get("chapTitle")
        content = self.request.get("content")
        note = self.request.get("note")
```

What do I need to do here to get this referencing working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of @dlorenc answer works, because on the NewChap it doesn't work. So this is how i got it working:

in NewTut hadler:

```
self.redirect('/newchap?tutorial_id=%s' % tut.key)
```

and in the NewChap handler, on the post:

```
tutID = self.request.get("tutorial_id")
tutorial = db.Key.from_path('Tutorial', tutID)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to pass the tutorial id to the next page through the URL. You could do this as a get parameter, or just part of the path. Here's how to do it as a get parameter:

```
self.redirect('/newchap?tutorial_id=%s' % tut.key)
```

Then, in your NewChap handler:

```
tutorial_id = request.get("tutorial_id")
tutorial = db.Key.from_path('Tutorial', tutID)
```

Comment: Almost there... i get this error:

`BadArgumentError: Expected an instance or iterable of (<type 'int'>, <type 'long'>); received <bound method Tutorial.key of <main.Tutorial object at 0x487a1d0>> (a unicode).`

Also... passing a key on the URL is safe??

Comment: It's as safe as any other method. With that said, you will need to add on an authorization system to verify the user has permissions to access the Tutorial they are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect to `'/newchap/%s' %tut.key.id()` and then fetch the id out in the request.

Comment: i got ths error refering to self.redirect('/newchap/%s' %tut.key.id())

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'id'